# Find $p(t)$ if $p'(t) = Ap(t) + Bp(0)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Given

$$
p(0) = 800000,
$$
$$
p'(t) = Ap(t) + Bp(0),
$$

where $A, B$ and $p(0)$ are constant and $p'(t)$ is the derivative of $p(t)$ at $t$.
I'm trying to work-out what $p(t)$ is.

I know that if the second (constant) term wasn't there the answer would be

$$p(t) = p(0)e^{At}$$

but it is there and I have the feeling I can't just integrate the $Bp(0)$ term and add it like

$$p(t) = p(0) e^{At} + Bp(0)t$$

The reason I think it is incorrect is because the graphs those equations produce don't make sense.
I know very little about all of this so my guess might even be correct but if it's not I would very much appreciate some advice or pointers on where to start.

Comment: Consider $q(t) = e^{-At}p(t)$. What is $q'(t)$?

Comment: Isn't this a standard integrating factor problem?

Comment: Hint: the equation is separable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exploiting Leibniz Notation:

$$\frac{dp}{dt} = Ap + Bp_0$$

Divide both sides by right hand side:

$$\frac{1}{Ap +Bp_0} \frac{dp}{dt} = 1$$

Distribute differentials

$$\frac{1}{Ap +Bp_0} dp = dt$$

Integrate both sides

$$\int \frac{1}{Ap + Bp_0} dp = \int dt$$

To find:

$$\frac{1}{A} \ln(Ap + Bp_0) = t + C$$

Solve for P:

$$Ap + Bp_0 = Ce^{At}$$

Therefore:

$$p = Ce^{At} - \frac{B}{A}p_0$$

Now use your skills of algebra to find a C that satisfies

$$p_0 = Ce^{A*0} - \frac{B}{A}p_0$$

Comment: This yields the function P that you are looking for.

Comment: @Levix Thanks guys. Now the graphs do make sense.

Answer (score 0):

$$p(t) = c_1 e^{A t}-\frac{800000 B}{A}$$ if this makes more sense as a result (i am not quite sure whether I got your question right) I could explain how to find it. Just ask.